# How to compute CDF for a mixed random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having trouble putting the things together while computing the CDF for a mixed (discrete-continuous) random variable. Here's what I have:

1) $X,Y,Z$ are r.v.'s, $P(X=Y)=5/6,P(X=Z)=1/6$

2) $Y:y\in \{0,5\}$.

$p_{Y}(y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
4/5, & y=0\\
1/5, & y=5
\end{array}\right.$

3) $f_{Z}(z)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1/5, & 0<z<5\\
0, & otherwise
\end{array}\right.$

From that I compute the following:

$F_{Y}(y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
4/5, & y<5\\
1, & y\geq5
\end{array}\right.$

$F_{Z}(z)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
z/5, & 0<z<5\\
1, & z\geq5
\end{array}\right.$

And now I want to apply the formula $F_{X}(x)=P(A)*F_{Y}(x)+(1-P(A))*F_{Z}(x)$ and here I'm not sure what to put in it instead of $F_Y(y)$ and $F_Z(z)$, because each function is made up of 2 values depending on the value of their arguments.

Comment: Try, for every nonnegative $y$ and $z$, $$F_Y(y)=\frac45+\frac15\mathbf 1_{y\geqslant5}\qquad F_Z(z)=\frac15\min\{z,5\}$$ hence, for every nonnegative $x$, $$F_X(x)=\frac56F_Y(x)+\frac16F_Z(x)=\frac23+\frac1{30}\min\{x,5\}+\frac16\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant5}$$ Not sure the CDF provides the best description of the distribution of $X$, though...